# Is there a way to override native accelerator keys?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jmenuitem, acceleratorkey

I have a JList filled with entries that the native copy method can't handle. I have a method that effectively copies and formats the selected data in just the way I want and I want this method to be called when ctrl + c is used but unfortunately JList is already listing for those accelerator keys so when I set them for my copy function in my JMenu it doesn't work unless I give the JMeny focus. Is there anyway that I can make ctrl + c use my copy method instead of the native one other than having to click on the JMenu every time I want to copy something?

Comment: Add a key binding for the key-stroke you want to use...[How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  You could also add a `Action` for the binding `copy`...

Comment: Wowza, from what I read in your link and it seems there is no way around converting my copy method into an action but that stuff gets pretty complex... I already have copy bound to keystrokes using 'copy.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));' is there anyway I can just make JList have the same effect when I press ctrl +c without having to spend all day learning how to use actions?

Comment: `there is no way around converting my copy method into an action but that stuff gets pretty complex... ` - why do you say it is complicated? An Action is basically just an ActionListener. You add the code to the actionPerformed() method of your custom Copy Action.

Comment: I think [How To Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) just didn't provide any good examples/was kind of hard to understand for me. This [Java Key Binding Tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/245148-java-key-binding-tutorial-and-demo-program/) helped me understand it a little better

Comment: By the way -> `copy.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));` is not really a key binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Start by creating a `Action` which describes what it does and how it does.  In this case, you may need to supply the `JList` from which you want to copy from (I'd have some kind of `interface` which provided a simply "copy" method of some kind, but that's just me)

```
public class CopyAction extends AbstractAction {

    private JList list;

    public CopyAction(JList list) {
        putValue(NAME, "Copy");
        putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_C);
        putValue(SELECTED_KEY, "Copy stuff");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("All your copies belong to us");
    }

    public JList getList() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

Now, add a key binding to a `JList`, along with your `Action`...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private JList listOfStuff;

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        listOfStuff = new JList();
        add(new JScrollPane(listOfStuff));

        CopyAction copyAction = new CopyAction(listOfStuff);
        listOfStuff.getActionMap().put("copy", copyAction);
    }

    public JList getListOfStuff() {
        return listOfStuff;
    }

}
```

Now, you can use the `Action` with buttons as well...

```
TestPane tp = new TestPane();
CopyAction copyAction = new CopyAction(tp.getListOfStuff());

JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Edit");
mb.add(menu);
menu.add(copyAction);

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
```

And a fully runnable example....

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public class CopyAction extends AbstractAction {

        private JList list;

        public CopyAction(JList list) {
            putValue(NAME, "Copy");
            putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_C);
            putValue(SELECTED_KEY, "Copy stuff");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("All your copies belong to us");
        }

        public JList getList() {
            return list;
        }

    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TestPane tp = new TestPane();
                CopyAction copyAction = new CopyAction(tp.getListOfStuff());

                JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu menu = new JMenu("Edit");
                mb.add(menu);
                menu.add(copyAction);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JList listOfStuff;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            listOfStuff = new JList();
            add(new JScrollPane(listOfStuff));

            CopyAction copyAction = new CopyAction(listOfStuff);
            listOfStuff.getActionMap().put("copy", copyAction);
        }

        public JList getListOfStuff() {
            return listOfStuff;
        }

    }

}
```